# initialization code placement for ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

One of my page has buttons like- btnNext, btnPrevious, btnZoomIn, btnZoomOut and a div housing a  tag. The images are loaded from the database.

I am using  'smooth zoom pan' plugin (http://vectorflower.com/preview/smooth_zoom/) on the images to achieve Zoom In and Zoom Out functions.I invoke the zoom in & zoom out functions using the code:

```
<script>
jQuery(function($){
    initSmoothZoom();
});

function initSmoothZoom(){
    $('#pgimg').smoothZoom({
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        zoom_BUTTONS_SHOW : 'NO',
        pan_BUTTONS_SHOW : 'NO',
        pan_LIMIT_BOUNDARY : 'YES',
        zoom_MAX:800,
        zoom_MIN:100,
        responsive: true,
        responsive_maintain_ratio: true,
        border_TRANSPARENCY: 0,
    });
}
</script>
```

Navigation buttons - btnNext & btnPrevious when clicked loads new image from the database using ajax.

The first time when the page loads, zoom in & zoom out functions work perfectly. However, when next image is loaded using ajax by the navigation buttons, the zoom in & zoom out function don't work. They begin to work only after hitting refresh.

I tried to call the zoom in & zoom out initialization code inside the ajax: success function, even then it does not work.

```
function loadNextImage(){
....................
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>pages/load_req_page_via_navigator/",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {..........................},
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#loader").show();
            },
            success:function(result){
                destroy_ias();
                initSmoothZoom();//<------------------

                $("#canvas").html(result);                                       
            },
            error: function(result)
            {
                alert('error:'+result);
            },
            fail:(function(result) {
                alert('fail:'+result);
            }),
            complete: function() {
                $("#loader").hide();
            }
        });
 }
...................
}
```

Please tell someone, as where should i placed the initialization so that it will work.

Comment: Without seeing how you are loading a new image from ajax, I'm taking a shot in the dark saying it has to do with you not adding .smoothZoom to the new image.

Comment: @Ryan pls see my updated code.

Comment: Call initSmoothZoom(); after you add result to the canvas in the success callback function of your ajax.

Comment: Did as suggested. Weird behaviour noticed.The ajax code works, it loads a new image but its dimension is 0x0. No error noticed except that the image size is 0x0

Comment: Sounds like you haven't set the width and height properties of the new img element

Comment: Thanks @Ryan, you pointed me in the right direction.